# How to remove (trim) text from a shape in Corel Draw?

Tags: corel-draw

I have a simple shape and with that a text converted.

I want to trim the converted text to that shape so that I can see the blue color i.e transparent.

Whats the problem with it? Why its not trimming?

Download the file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiTD4qoMzsZclNicWkzYWZERFk)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum. I downloaded it and could nof find the problematic node.

That happens sometines when two noedes overlap at the exact same place, but I could not find it on the shapes.

The two shapes does trim with the blue rectangle but do not trim on each other.

The workarround I did was to convert the white shape to raster and vectorizing it again. This produced new nodes, and they now can be combined to make the text transparent.

Comment: well i want to solve with that same shape. I have made the boundary and then fill the color white and the trim it work other than raster and then vectorizing. I want to know why it did not work to the same vector whats the issue to that vector. Thanks